# Subroutine overwriting with shared objects

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, overwrite

I need to have two version of the same code compiled with different compilation options. At run-time my code decides which version to use. On windows I solved this problem by statically linking to one version and dynamically linking to a ddl containing the other version plus a wrapper to change the names of the entry points. But on Linux I do not manage to get the same behavior.

Here is the problem:
I have a executable “X.exe” which contains symbol “A” but also links to a shared object “B.so”. This “B.so” has also a symbol “A” and a symbol “B” that call “A” (B is actually a wrapper around the other version of “A”). The problem however is that when I call “B” in the “X.exe”, this “B” call the “A” from the “X.exe” and not the one from the “B.so”. I tried to restrict the visibility but when I do so I get an error when allocating memory inside “B.so”.

Additionally B.so also need a different version of multiple 3rd-party libraries which are either statically or dynamically linked.

How do I need to compile and link my code on linux to get the same behavior as on windows (ie. everything is resolved internally first)?

Comment: Are you talking about C or C++ compilers? You should add the appropriate tags then.

Comment: Don't do that. Load both versions dynamically (but only one at a time). That's much easier than trying to emulate Windows DLLs with Linux shared objects.

Comment: So you have two B and two A, one of each in X.exe and one of each in B.so, correct? And B is the wrapper, which calls A. Where is the point of the wrapper then?

Comment: @ TORBJORN, Actually it is fortran (and some C files as well) but this should not matter since in a pure linking problem.

Comment: @Ctx, No the wrapper B only exists in the shared object. So when I need to call the "other A" I can call B instead.

Comment: @GertMassa Then I do not understand, why the "other A" has to be called "A". Why not call it A2 and call that from the wrapper "B"?

Comment: Partial solution: Adding the compiler options "-fvisibility=hidden" when compiling the code part of the X.exe solves the issue in a simplified case. But when I need to link to different version of external libraries (no code available, so can not recompile) I looks like I have the same issue again.

I also realized that the allocation problem I had was actually a wrong error message in the 3rd-party code. The real problem was the need of two different version of the mpi libraries.

Comment: @Ctx, because the code of the two version of A are identical. Only the compiler options change. I do not want to rename hundreds of subroutines names of code I barely understand.

Comment: @GertMassa You might try to strip the symbol A from the dynamic symbol table of "X.exe" (e.g. with `strip -N A X.exe`) Then it shouldn't be possible for B.so to call the A in X.exe